# PC817 input features

Tags: led, ac, diodes, opto-isolator, reverse-breakdown

I'm designing a new circuit and I need to know if PC817 allows AC voltage input around 230V.
I've tried with DC Voltage but never AC Voltage.
Does anyone know if it operates with AC input?

Comment: There are AC optocouplers, or you can put a diode in anti parallel with the input to protect it from reverse voltage.

Answer (score 3):

In the reverse direction, no current would flow through the diode (initially), so there would be no voltage dropped over the resistor, so the IR LED in the PC817 would see the whole voltage of 325 V (DC). The PC817 has a reverse voltage rating (V<sub>R</sub>) of 6 V, so it would blow up.

You could instead use the PC814, which has similar characteristics, but an AC input with two antiparallel LEDs:

[image: PC814]

Alternatively, just put a diode like that in the front of the PC817. (Then the output of the PC817 would switch on only every second half wave.)

Answer (score 0):

NO AC , this would exceed reverse DC voltage rating.

[image]